# Detect when template.dynamic changes

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

Is there any way to detect when the `{{>Template.dynamic template=content}}` changes and then run some functions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your functions in a `template.autorun()` block, in the dynamic template you are rendering (in his `rendered` function) .

If you need to follow it from outside, you can use the tracker Deps feature: you declare the change in the autorun block.